# Set a Date from string in swift 3

Tags: mysql, date, swift3, xcode8

I need to assign a value 'datetime' mysql dbase to variable type Date(). 
The record will be import from httprequest as string. 
Then I would like to set a Date() from a string format.
So i have this function:

```
func parseDate(dateStr:String, format:String="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") -> Date {

  let myLocale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
  let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
  dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CEST")
  dateFormat.locale = myLocale
  dateFormat.dateStyle = .medium
  dateFormat.timeStyle = .medium
  dateFormat.dateFormat = format

  return dateFmt.date(from: dateStr)
}
```

I have this error: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Date?' to return type 'Date'" on return line.

How can I resolve it.

Comment: Make your function return `Date?`, in case it cannot parse the string.

Comment: How can I make this function as optional return value

Comment: Don't set your locale or timeZome manually. If there is no timezone in your date String just use the Date Formatter defaults for Locale and timezone (the default is local time)

Comment: Instead of `-> Date` In the method declaration, it's `-> Date?`.

Answer (score 0):

In swift optional types and non-optional counterparts cannot be treated as the same type, i.e. `Date` and `Date?` are different types.

The `date(from: String)` function returns an optional `Date` - `Date?` and your function returns a non-optional `Date`.

To fix your function either return an optional value by changing `...-> Date {` to `...-> Date?` or return a non-optional value by optional expansion on your return statement: `return dateFmt.date(from: dateStr) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`

Comment: I'd definitely advise using the optional pattern. The whole idea of optionals in Swift is to have a predictable, reliable sentinel value. Using something like `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)` is antithetical to this design concept.

Comment: I actually agree with @Rob I added the expansion for completeness only

Comment: I have changed method declaration in `func parseDate(dateStr:String, format:String="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") -> Date? {....` and return statement `return dateFmt.date(from: dateStr)`. 
Now i have this error `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Date?' to return type 'Date?'`